# ASP NET ENtity FrameWork trabajando con archivos

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Hola amigos estoy usando **ASP NET ENTITY FRAMEWORK** para hacer un projecto web, quiero recibir un archivo y guardarlo en mi proyecto, para al final solo guardar el path del archivo en mi base de datos, pero tengo problemas para recibir el archivo, tengo un método que recibe un modelo de datos, recibo TODO menos el archivo, alguien podría ayudarme por favor.

Este es mi modelo.

```
public class ProductoFinanciero
{
    public IList<IFormFile> files { get; set; }

    public string title { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public string montoCredito { get; set; }
    public string plazoMinimo { get; set; }
    public string plazoMaximo { get; set; }
    public string frecuenciasDePago { get; set; }
    public string esquemaDeCobro { get; set; }
    public string requisitos { get; set; }
    public string tasaDeInteres { get; set; }
    public string CAT { get; set; }
    public string CATDescripcion { get; set; }
    public string lastupdate { get; set; }
    public string id_userCreated { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }

}
```

este es mi metodo

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertProductoFinanciero(ProductoFinanciero data)
    {


        var fx = data.files[0]; -- mi error está aqu

        /*
        Mi  Code que hace varias cosas*/

        return View("Index");
    }
```

este es el error que me manda

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección.
>   Nombre del parámetro: index'

Ý este el formulario donde mando todo

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("InsertProductoFinanciero", "DashboardAdmin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "productoFinForm" }))
    {

        <input type="text" name="id_userCreated" class="hidden" value="@User.Identity.GetUserId()" />
        <img id="PreviewImage" class="" width="180" height="240" src=""
             alt="Imagen de crédito" style="height:100px;" required />

        <br>
        <input name="files" id="file_prodfin" onchange="readURL(this);" type="file"
                />

        </script>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="titleCredito" placeholder="Nombre del Producto / Credito EJEMPLO" required />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descripcion" id="descrpcionCredito" placeholder="Descripción" required />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="montoCredito" id="montoCredito" placeholder="Monto de Crédito" required />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="plazoMinimo" id="plazoMinimoCredito" placeholder="Plazo Máximo" required />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="plazoMaximo" id="plazoMaximoCredito" placeholder="Plazo Mínimo" required />

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frecuenciasDePago" id="frecuenciaDePagosCredito" placeholder="Frecuencia De Pagos" required/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="esquemaDeCobro" id="esquemaDeCobroCredito" placeholder="Esquema De Cobro" required/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="requisitos" id="requisitosCredito" placeholder="Requisitos" required/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tasaDeInteres" id="tasaDeInteresPonderadaAnualCredito" placeholder="Tasa De Interes Ponderada Anual" required/>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CAT" id="costoTotalAnualCredito" placeholder="Descripción Tasa De Interes Ponderada Anual" required />

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CATDescripcion" id="costoTotalAnualDescripcionCredito" placeholder="Costo Total Anual Descripcion" required />
        <br />

        <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-default" name="" id="productoFinForm" placeholder="Crear" />

    }
```

Aquí les dejo una imagen de lo que recibo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304617/html-helper-for-input-type-file), creo que te falta `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` por eso no recibes los archivos

Comment: pues se ñp aregue al form y al input y nada :s

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas la documentacion de dotNet al respecto ya que con intentar acceder al objeto files no es suficiente y por eso te da el error: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: ¿Has colocado algún breakpoint antes del error y visto lo que trae la variable `data` ?